# Forming a sentences with given words/phrases

Tags: sentence

A question in an English exercise. There are a few words/phrases given to form a sentence (punctuation to be added).

The words are:

- breakfast
- I have
- fit for
- that is
- every morning
- a king

The answer I worked out is:

```
That is a king breakfast I have fit for every morning.
```

It means, "I'm having this big breakfast every morning."

Not sure if it is right. Can you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Try again! . . .

Comment: Hint: ["fit for a king"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fit+for+a+king) is a standard English idiom.

Comment: @Xanne, and nnnnnnn, Thank you for the comments and hint! Is it in this way? "That is breakfast I have fit for a king every morning."

Comment: This is not the place to come to with your homework problems. This is too trivial for an English exercise since any combination that is a valid sentence would be discounted for subjective reasons of the teacher. Not a lesson. Not a valid question for our site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Every morning, I have breakfast that is fit for a king.